# How do I compile all .c files in my code directory?

Tags: c, makefile, mingw

I made a template folder for SDL2 projects. I followed this tutorial from Lazy Foo: *http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/windows/mingw/index.php* to create my makefile.

**My makefile:**

```
OBJS = ..\code\main.c
CC = gcc
INCLUDE_PATHS = -IC:\mingw-libraries\include\SDL2
LIBRARY_PATHS = -LC:\mingw-libraries\lib
COMPILER_FLAGS = -w 
LINKER_FLAGS = -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2
OBJ_NAME = main.exe

all : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) $(INCLUDE_PATHS) $(LIBRARY_PATHS) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) $(LINKER_FLAGS) -o $(OBJ_NAME)
```

So this works when I want to compile main.c, but when I want to compile everything in the code directory
I get this:

**makefile**:

```
OBJS = ..\code\*.c
CC = gcc
INCLUDE_PATHS = -IC:\mingw-libraries\include\SDL2
LIBRARY_PATHS = -LC:\mingw-libraries\lib
COMPILER_FLAGS = -w 
LINKER_FLAGS = -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2
OBJ_NAME = main.exe

all : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) $(INCLUDE_PATHS) $(LIBRARY_PATHS) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) $(LINKER_FLAGS) -o $(OBJ_NAME)
```

This is the error I get:
`mingw32-make: *** No rule to make target '..\code\*.c', needed by 'all'.  Stop.`

Comment: Try `OBJS = $(wildcard ../code/*.c)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any of the below way to get the list of *.c files in the code directory:

Using find :

```
OBJS := $(shell find ../code/ -name *.c)
```

OR

Using wildcard :

```
OBJS = $(wildcard ../code/*.c)
```

I would also recommend to change the name of `OBJS` to maybe something like `SOURCES`.
 As `OBJS` interprates as object files (.o) and in `make` we have this as different steps for object creation and to generate an executable.